# Main function's arguments, cant understand this!

Tags: c, function, program-entry-point

Why is my code under giving me back "Not a valid command" when i give the argument print ?

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    printf("Argument 2 er %s\n", argv[1]);

    if(argv[1] == "print") {
        printf("Print kommando kalt");
    } else if(argv[1] == "random") {
        printf("Random kommando kalt");
    } else if(argv[1] == "replace") {
        printf("Replace kommando kalt");
    } else if(argv[1] == "remove") {
        printf("Remove kommando kalt");
    } else if(argv[1] == "len") {
        printf("øem kommando kalt");
    } else {
        printf("Ingen gyldig kommando\n");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 13):

You cannot compare C strings using `==`. This only does a pointer comparison. You need to use `strcmp` instead:

```
if (strcmp(argv[1], "print") == 0) …
```

Answer (score 8):

Because you cannot compare strings like that in C.

You need to use:

```
if(strcmp(argv[1], "print") == 0)
  printf("Print kommando kalt\n");
```

And so on.

Also, make sure you don't access `argv[1]` without making sure it's really there and valid; if your program gets called with no arguments it will be NULL. You can use the value of `argc` to determine how many arguments you got.

Comment: @Oli: `argv[argc]` (values at start of main) is guaranteed to be NULL by the Standard

Answer (score 2):

Because `argv[1]` is a `char*`: something like 0xDEADBEEF
and "print" behaves as if it is **another** `char*`: something like 0xBADF00D

and 0xDEADBEEF != 0xBADF00D

You want to use `strcmp()` ( http://linux.die.net/man/3/strcmp )

Comment: Ha... +1 for the DEADBEEF reference

Comment: I'd give it a +1 if you'd used 0xDECAFBAD. :-)